# Why `if (a = b)` won't work for comparison in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a string that if b (the password) = a (hello) it will alert "jj" and if not "nope" but I can't figure out why it won't work. I know this isn't how passwords are properly stored.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="button" value="run js" onclick="start()">

<br><br>

UserName: <input type="text" id="userName">

Password: <input type="password" id="pasWord">


<p>hello</p>

<button onclick="passWord()"></button>


<script>
function start() {
    var a = ("hello");
}
function passWord() {
    var b = document.getElementById("pasWord").innerHTML;
    if (a = b) {
        alert("jj");
    } else {
        alert("nope");
    }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Answer (score 1):

This `a = b` isn't correct. It should change to the following:

```
a === b
```

Inside an if statement you should have only expressions that can be evaluated as booleans (true/false). Apparently, this `a=b` is an assignment of `b` to `a` and it isn't an expression that can be evaluated to true or false.

Furthermore, here `b = document.getElementById("pasWord").innerHTML` you should access the `value` attribute and not `innerHTML`, since this contains the value you are looking for.

Last but not least, you should see the declaration of the variable `a`. As it is, `a` is not accessible in `passWord` function.

You could try something like the following (despite it's a bit meaningless :))

```js
var a;

function start() {
    a = "hello";
}

function passWord() {
    var b = document.getElementById("pasWord").value;
    if (a === b) {
        alert("jj");
    } else {
        alert("nope");
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="run js" onclick="start()">
<br/>
UserName: <input type="text" id="userName">
Password: <input type="password" id="pasWord">
<p>hello</p>
<button onclick="passWord()">password</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

using single "=" sign will assign the value to that variable. In your case use == or === to check if that String variable A is equal to "hello"

here is the solution :)

```
<script>
function start() {
    var a = ("hello");
}
function passWord() {
    var b = document.getElementById("pasWord").innerHTML;
    if (a === b) {
        alert("jj");
    } else {
        alert("nope");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things are wrong here:

- You access `.innerHTML` which is not the value of and input. To access the value use `document.getElementById("pasWord").value`.
- You try to compare `a` and `b` with `a = b` which is an assignment, to compare use `==` or `===`: `a === b`.
- You declare `a` in the context of the `start` function, so its not accessible in the `passWord` function. You can either store it globally (just replace `var a = ("hello");` with `a = ("hello");`, or better, access it directly in the `passWord` function.

Answer (score 0):

you assigning `b` value to `a`. not comparing. To compare two value use `===` or `==`.